# How to find which part of my Rust project uses GLIBC 2.18

Tags: linux, rust, redhat, glibc

With `cargo-tree`, I can see my project depends on `libc v0.2.62`

```
$ cargo tree -p libc -i | grep libc
libc v0.2.62
```

But it actually requires two versions `GLIB_2.14` and `GLIBC2.18`. 
`ldd` error messages are as follows:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

I am able to get `GLIBC_2.14` but not `GLIBC_2.18`. So I plan to switch to older versions of Rust or some crates I use. I need to find out which one depends on `GLIBC_2.18` first. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

To see which symbols reference `GLIBC_2.18`, you can use `eu-readelf`:

```
$ eu-readelf -s /usr/bin/cargo  | grep -F @GLIBC_2.18
  157: 0000000000000000      0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    UNDEF __cxa_thread_atexit_impl@GLIBC_2.18 (19)
```

This symbol is used by the Rust runtime itself to implement destructors (the `Drop` trait) for TLS variables.

If this is about getting Rust to work on Red Hat Enterprise Linux, you should be using [Rust Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_tools/2019.3/html/using_rust_toolset/index). It is regularly rebased against the latest upstream version, so its Rust version is fairly current most of the time.

Comment: Yes, this is about getting Rust to work on RHEL. Unfortunately I am not able to get Rust Toolset. Is there another way around? Can I avoid using `GLIBC_2.18` by downgrading my Rust?

Comment: Isn't Rust Toolset part of the free developer subscription? Or is the problem that you cannot install any RPM packages on the host?

Comment: The rust dev toolset is not blessed by my admin. I can't install it. Need to find a way to work around.

Comment: You need to work with your administrator towards a solution. Rust Toolset *is* the proper way to install the Rust compiler on Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Comment: But I don't need a rust compiler. I can cross-compile on another machine and ship the binary to RHEL. I just have missing libraries. `GLIBC_2.18` is not available on RHEL7 (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3643072), so I am looking for a way to downgrade my Rust cross-compiler.

Comment: The Rust compiler in Rust Toolset will produce compatible binaries. Just use that. Install Red Hat Enterprise Linux in a VM, or talk to your administrator to provide it to you.

Comment: New question as a follow up of these comments: [How can I specify the GLIBC version in cargo build for Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749127/how-can-i-specify-the-glibc-version-in-cargo-build-for-rust).