# How can I specify the GLIBC version in cargo build for Rust?

Tags: rust, glibc, rust-cargo

I use rust 1.34 and 1.35. Currently it links to `GLIBC_2.18`.

How can I limit `cargo build` to link `GLIBC` up to version `2.14`?

Comment: Something like [this](https://redbeardlab.com/2019/05/07/rust-and-glibc-version/)?

Comment: @jhpratt Thanks but `musl` doesn't work for me because I also use other system libraries such as `openssl`.

Comment: Google? [Minimum Supported glibc version](https://github.com/rust-lang/libc/issues/1412), [How to compile rust with a specific GLIBC version](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-compile-rust-with-a-specific-glibc-version-for-gnueabihf-architecture/6680), [Rust binaries require a too recent glibc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57497), ...

Comment: the three links provided don't provide a great solution for this problem. this question appears to be still valid

Comment: I'm discovering this now. You can't compile from Linux to Linux without using an outdated machine or a container. I can't hardly believe it.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you can't. Not really, and not consistently. This is a problem with any binary that dynamically links to GLIBC. You can try [setting up multiple GLIBC versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host) and linking to one, or you can try [patching the resulting binary](https://www.lightofdawn.org/wiki/wiki.cgi/NewAppsOnOldGlibc), but it's inconsistent and impractical.

So what are some practical options?

1. **Compile Statically**

By using MUSL instead of GLIBC we can compile statically.

To install the MUSL target with `rustup` (assuming x86_64 architecture):

```
$ rustup component add rust-std-x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

And to use it when compiling:

```
$ cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

This is the easiest method by far, but won't always work, especially when using native libraries, unless they can also be compiled statically.

2. **Make a VM That Has an Older Version**

This is a common approach. By using an OS with an outdated, GLIBC the binary will have GLIBC symbols that are compatible with it.

3. **Use a Docker Container**

This is probably the most convenient method, in my opinion. If you have Docker, you can just compile your project with a container that contains an old GLIBC. View the Rust contianer's [README](https://hub.docker.com/_/rust) for compilation instructions. The command below will compile a project using Rust 1.67 and GLIBC 2.28 (which comes with buster):

```
$ docker run --rm --user "$(id -u)":"$(id -g)" -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp rust:1.67-buster cargo build --release
```

I compiled this on Ubuntu 22.04 and tested it on Ubuntu 20.04.

To test further, I made sure the binary relied on another dynamic library (OpenSSL) and here's the result of `ldd ./mybinary` after compiling with the Docker container:

```
$ ldd ./mybinary 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd98fdf000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fe49e248000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe49e22d000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe49e223000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe49e200000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe49e0b1000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe49e0ab000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe49deb7000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe49ea30000)
```

And this is what it looks like without the container:

```
$ ldd ./mybinary
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd5d7b7000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007fe85564c000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe85562c000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe855545000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe85531d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe855f98000)
```

Comment: The second option thats the one that work for me. I virtualize an older Ubuntu version , and compile there what I need

Answer (score 2):

I just found out about [zigbuild](https://github.com/rust-cross/cargo-zigbuild), this project can enable you to do this by specifying a target with a glibc version at the end:
`cargo zigbuild --target aarch64-uknown-linux-gnu.2.14` (or whatever target you are aiming for)

Note that you also need to have [zig](https://ziglang.org/learn/getting-started/#installing-zig) installed for this method.

Comment: Worked for me when building from Debian (WSL) with `GLIBC 2.36` to CentOS7 with `GLIBC 2.17`.